# jquery expanding and shrinking rows applying only on first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make one row here to expand on user click and slide up when user click on another row or click on it again,

I have tried the following code below and it seem to only apply on first row and doesn't on rest rows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sRow').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('.details').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).find('.details').slideDown('600');
    }else{
      $(this).find('.details').slideUp('600');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.details { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something here
  <div class="details">
    <hr>
    some detail
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something else here
  <div class="details">
    <hr>
    some other detail
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something else here
  <div class="details">
    <hr>
    some other detail
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use class instead of ID.
2. ID should be unique on context

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sRow').click(function() {
    $('.details:visible').slideUp('600');
    if (!$(this).find('.details').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).find('.details').slideDown('600');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.details').slideUp('600');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something here
  <div class="details">
    <hr> some detail
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something else here
  <div class="details">
    <hr> some other detail
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="sRow" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px #000 solid;">
  Something else here
  <div class="details">
    <hr> some other detail
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks.
Also, How can i close other expanded rows when user focus on one

Comment: you add this line `$('.details:visible').slideUp('600');` before your if statement it means it will slideUp the visible details @hackerman